# Facebook authentication results in a 404 page not found

Tags: meteor

I have a problem with facebook integration in meteor with a 404 on the last step of authentication. When i click on the login with facebook button (accounts ui), it pops up the facebook u/p screen and i enter details in correctly, fb then tries to send the following:

```
http://localhost/_oauth/facebook?close&code=XXXXXXX
```

Which results in a 404 page does not exist.... any ideas?

**Update** not that it should matter: i am using meteor on windows.

**Update** it seems that the problem is with the port. Both google and facebook are returning back to localhost and not localhost:3000 the default meteor port.

Does anyone know how to set that it redirects to port 3000 and not :80. If i start meteor --port 80 it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: I remember encountering something like this before. May I know what is the url that you set in your fb app?

Comment: I have not configured any URLs... i basically followed this post: http://bulenttastan.net/login-with-facebook-using-meteor-js/ - its basically a stock setup of facebook for meteor